# MongoDB, WiredTiger: Need to update one field in all documents (700k). Which side-effects will occur?

Tags: mongodb, wiredtiger

One of the collections has documents with a field `"sc":[float]`. I want to iterate all documents and change this to `"sc": float`, that is, remove the array and assign the float value directly to the key.

Isn't it true, that WiredTiger appends all updated documents instead of trying to do some in-place updates like MMap?

This would basically double the size of the database, with the initial half being obsolete data.

Do I need to call `mongod -repair` in order to discard those obsolete documents, or is there something else I need to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WT is always rewriting documents when updated, but instead of NMAP it is not using padding, and allocating documents in free blocks, so if we have document 1,2,3 - there is a chance that no1 will be moved to end of a file (or closest gap), and no2 will be allocated in previous no1 space.

what is important about WT:

> WiredTiger does ongoing compaction and reuse of space automatically.

To ensure that file is used efficiency we can enforce WT to use smaller page size as per [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongodb-user/nV-DWbgB2oM) discussion.

```
--wiredTigerCollectionConfigString="leaf_page_max=8KB"
```

Also `compact` could be use to reclaim space [more here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/compact/).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I tested it (some weeks ago) on a duplicate dataset and saw that all was OK, so i just applied it to the live dataset. It worked, and up until your explanation I was wondering why. It just didn't come into my mind that they would reuse the freed space... shame on me.